# How to change the background color of an input field of a Django form if it contains errors

Tags: html, css, django, forms

I'm trying to code a form with fields that, if a user inputs data that doesn't pass the validation of the form, change their background colors from the default white to lightcoral.

Here is a fragment of the HTML file that contains the form itself:

```
 <div id="div_formbox">
        <form method="post" id="form_appointments">
            {% csrf_token %}
            
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                          
            <div class="input_group">
                
                <div class="input_field {% if form.name.errors %}error{% endif %}">
                    {{ form.name}}
                </div>
                
                <div class="input_field {% if form.last_name.errors %}error{% endif %}">
                    {{ form.last_name }}
                </div>
                                              
                
                <div class="input_field {% if form.email.errors %}error{% endif %}">
                    {{ form.email }}
                </div>
                               
       
            </div>
    
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And here is the part of the CSS file where I try to apply the color change to the input fields with errors:

```
.error {
   background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

As you can see, I'm using Django tags to change the class of the form fields with errors from "input_field" to "error".
Next, in the CSS file, I reference the "error" class to apply the styling I want. But it doesn't work. I've tried a bunch of variations but none have worked. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try like below.

```css
.error {
   background-color: lightcoral !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open developer tools in your browser and check if the CSS file is loaded, the class name, and the properties of the element in styles section below the Element tab, make sure that everything is actually in its desired form. It may be that the css file was not correctly.

What is the type of the `form` argument passed in your view function?
`form.name.errors` is a little confusing since form must be a model and name is a property (maybe a `CharField`), but still you access `error` property of the field which is not mentioned in [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field) as a standard built-in option.

Comment: Did you add static files (css file) in the right way as mentionted in [Docs - Customize your app’s look and feel](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial06/)